# Almost sure convergence of a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, recursion, random-walk

I just learned martingales (with no depth) and I am working on the following question.

Suppose $S_n$ is a a random walk on the integers and at each step, it increases by 1 with probability $p$ or decreases by 1 with probability $1-p$.

Suppose $f(S_n)$ is an increasing function from $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$, and $f(S_n)$ is a martingale. I want to show $S_n$ is recurrent if and only if $\sup f=\infty$ and $\inf f=-\infty$.

Assume $S_n$ recurrent, and $\sup f=\infty$ and $\inf f=-\infty$ does NOT hold. $f(S_n)$ must be bounded (at least on one side), then $f(S_n)$ converges almost surely. I kind have the intuition that since $S_n$ has to increase or decrease by 1 as $n$ grows, to make $f(S_n)$ converges almost surely, $S_n$ can not go back to the same point infinitely often (being recurrent).

But I'm confused with the notion of almost sure converges of $f(S_n)$, what does it mean for $f(S_n)$ to converge almost surely?

Comment: It means $f(S_n(\omega))\rightarrow g(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in A$ for some measurable $\omega\rightarrow g(\omega)$ and measurable set $A$ with $P(A)=1$.

Comment: $A$ need not be measurable, but $A^c$ is a $P$-null set is enough

Comment: @user138668 Thank you. Could you say more about what is the sample space of $S_n(\omega)$? I mean what are the $\omega$? If $S_n=\sum_{i\le n}X_i$ where $X_i=1$ with probability $p_i$ and $-1$ otherwise.

Comment: To talk about a random walk or any random variable, you need a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ where all random variables are measurable mappings from this space to $\mathbb{R}$. If you have problems with this statement, you need to look at a serious introductory book such as Jacod & Protter, etc.. For your problem, $X_i(\omega)=1$ for $\omega\in B_i$ and $X_i(\omega)=-1$ for $\omega\in B_i^c$ for some *independent* sets $\{B_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}^+}$.